# Fire event when `optimize.activate` finishes?

Tags: google-optimize

GTM's `dataLayer` 'optimize.activate' `eventCallback` seems to fire before any DOM manipulation is complete.

For example, an "experiment" that manipulates a title on the DOM is activated using:

```
dataLayer.push({
  'event': 'optimize.activate',
  eventCallback: () => {
    ...do something with the new DOM
  }
})
```

But `...do something` gets called BEFORE the modification shows. Is there any way to be notified once all experiments are in place and ready?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Facing the same issue here & silence from the Google forums

Comment: No, never did. Ended up just using a setTimeout.

Comment: The JavaScript API is meant for this exact purpose, but it doesn't work for me. The callback never gets called. https://support.google.com/optimize/answer/9059383?hl=en&ref_topic=6315913

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same problem, and ended up firing it off manually when the JS was done:

```
dataLayer.push({'event': 'optimize.activate'})
```

Comment: I believe this is the opposite of what OP is asking.